# How should my PHP function handle invalid parameters?

Tags: php

I'm creating some re-usable functions, and right now I have error handling setup like this:

```
<?php
...
public function insertAfter( $index, $objects )
{
    if ( ! is_int( $index ) ) {
        trigger_error( 'Cursor::insertAfter() expects parameter 1 to be integer, ' . gettype( $index ) . ' given', E_USER_WARNING );
    } else {
        // Do my regular code
    }

    return $this;
}
...
```

I tried setting it up to work just like PHP would handle an error. Is this an appropriate way to do things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may throws an exception. Take a look at [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in PHP manual.

EDIT: Here are some useful SO threads.

1. [PHP Error handling: die() Vs trigger_error() Vs throw Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063053/php-error-handling-die-vs-trigger-error-vs-throw-exception).
2. [In PHP5, should I use Exceptions or trigger_error/set_error_handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607/in-php5-should-i-use-exceptions-or-trigger-error-set-error-handler).
3. [trigger_error vs. throwing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992078/trigger-error-vs-throwing-exceptions)

Comment: I had that originally, but I prefer not to litter my code with try catch statements

Comment: An [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://www.php.net/invalidargumentexception) would be most appropriate.

Comment: @Rogue You don't have to catch exceptions like this, that's the point. Passing an *invalid* argument type is not something that should be *caught*, it's an *exceptional mistake* that should stop your program and lead you to fix your code.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for point out [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://ca3.php.net/invalidargumentexception), this is exactly what I was looking for. Also, thank you for clarifying exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Altumo](http://github.com/homer6/altumo) package. It has quite a few handy validators that do what you are looking to do.

For example,

```
$index = \Altumo\Validation\Numerics::assertInteger( 
    $index, 
    'Cursor::insertAfter() expects parameter 1 to be integer, ' . gettype( $index ) . ' given'
);
```

There are [validators](https://github.com/homer6/altumo/tree/master/source/php/Validation) for Object types, strings, boolean, etc.

P.S. Exceptions are more flexible than trigger_error() because you can control them more granularly. [Here's a good thread on that topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607/in-php5-should-i-use-exceptions-or-trigger-error-set-error-handler)