# How to implement generic php exception handler

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

As shown in the php documentation is it possible to create your own [exception handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). I see this as a reasonable way to handle my user generated errors and exceptions throughout the project I am working on. Through research I have made a decent amount of progress in implementing a specific one, just for one class, including things like using [ErrorException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607/in-php5-should-i-use-exceptions-or-trigger-error-set-error-handler) (from the first answer) and making sure to return false for [error levels](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_error_handling.htm) that I can't handle.

I have however run into a wall with making it more generic. I don't want to have to write a separate handler for every class I write (especially because the vast majority of that code is going to be the same for every one). Yet it feels like terribly bad practice to have every single error for the entire project in the same handler.
The closest I have gotten to what feels like an acceptable solution is to write a subclass of ErrorException for every class I want to handle the errors for and store messages in each of those. But even with this I am probably going about it wrong (I don't think that would be the proper place to store default error messages).
 Is there a universally accepted way of doing this that I have been unable to find? or is one of these ways actually the way it's generally done? or are there multiple solutions that are scalable based on the size of the project?

EDIT: Just realized I can write a generic Exception_Handler with the reused code and extend it for each set of errors I have (real herp moment for me), but it still seems like I should handle all errors in the same place. If I'm completely wrong, let me know.


EDIT 2: Decided to go with a config file containing the error messages for each class that will throw errors, then the name of the class that throws the error defines what config file is loaded to get the list of messages associated with error number. This also allows me to easily define messages that should get logged as opposed to messages that should get sent to the user (essentially specific vs. generic messages).
I guess I'll mark this as answered or something, but if I'm doing something wrong feel free to let me know, help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with a config file containing the error messages for each class that will throw errors, then the name of the class that throws the error defines what config file is loaded to get the list of messages associated with error number. This also allows me to easily define messages that should get logged as opposed to messages that should get sent to the user (essentially specific vs. generic messages).
More specifically I'll probably use an ini file that defines an array of arrays where each number contains the array of error messages for that error number. Then use a foreach with the thrown error numbers to return the error message(s).