# set_error_handler vs set_exception_handler

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP5, should I use Exceptions or trigger_error/set_error_handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607/in-php5-should-i-use-exceptions-or-trigger-error-set-error-handler)

In PHP 5+, what is better to use?

- `set_error_handler`, because it can also trap errors which are not exceptions;
- `set_exception_handler`, because it's a new feature and it maybe came to replace `set_error_handler`; or
- both, because one does not supersedes the other, and both are useful?

Comment: Here [is][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607/in-php5-should-i-use-exceptions-or-trigger-error-set-error-handler

Comment: For better or worse (IMHO worse), exceptions and errors are almost completely unrelated in PHP. You need to handle both, and that will likely be the case forever.